# Mongoose. Como puedo obtener la información en el mismo orden que el esquema

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Existe alguna manera de obtener la información de mongoDB en el mismo orden que el esquema:

```
// Schema
const UsuarioSchema = new mongoose.Schema{
    {
         element1 : String,
         element2 : Number,
         element3 : Array,
         element4 : Number,
     }
}

// Consulta devuelve
var usuarios = {
    element1 : String,
    element2 : Number,
    element4 : Number,
    element3 : Array,
}
```

Gracias por su valiosa ayuda

Comment: Hola. Cual es el tu objetivo de ordenarlo de esa manera?

Comment: Que tal @Angel, realmente es por la facilidad de visualización, en el ejemplo puse un esquema con 4 campos pero tengo esquemas bastante complejos

Comment: Muestras el `json` directamente? O para fines de desarrollo?

Comment: Es para una api, entonces si devuelve el json directamente

Comment: Voy a actualizar mi respuesta con la razón de por que no se puede hacer con mucha confianza..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes intentar esto:

> ## [option: retainKeyOrder](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/4.x/docs/guide.html#retainKeyOrder)
>
> Por defecto, mongoose invierte el orden de las llaves como una optimización del rendimiento. Por ejemplo, `new Model ({first: 1, second: 2});` en realidad se almacenaría en MongoDB como `{second: 2, first: 1}`. Este comportamiento se considera obsoleto porque tiene numerosos efectos secundarios no deseados, incluida la dificultad para manipular documentos cuyo campo _id es un objeto.

```
var testSchema = new Schema({ first: Number, second: Number }, { retainKeyOrder: true });
```

---

No se puede controlar cómo se va a mostrar el JSON, pero una vez recibidos los datos, si puedes decidir como se muestran con `javascript` de manera programatica:

```js
var usuarios = {
    element4 : "Esta es la ultima propiedad",
    element1 : "Esta es la primera propiedad",     
    element2 : "Esta es la segunda propiedad",
    element3 : "Esta es la propiedad tercera",
}

//Obtenemos las llaves para ordenarlas
Object.keys(usuarios)
  //Ordenamos el arreglo de llaves.
  .sort((a, b)=> a > b ? 1:-1)
  //Recorremos el arreglo ordenado y mostramos cada elemento
  // con la ayuda del arreglo.
  .forEach(keyOrdenadas=>console.log(usuarios[keyOrdenadas]))
```

[Mas info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54872701/set-sort-order-for-mongoose-document)

Comment: Gracias lo probare